# how to get i-th element of queue in scala

Tags: scala

hello how can I access the i-th element of a queue in scala? The get method returns Option[type] and I get the following error

> Expression of type Option[multiSet] doesn't conform to expected type multiSet

the code I tried is:

```
var newSet:multiSet= new multiSet(r)
newSet = setQueue.get(i)
```

how can I solve this, should I use another data structure?

Comment: What's `multiSet`? `queue(i)` will return the i-th element (if it exists, and throw otherwise), but that is almost certainly a wrong thing to do. The answer to your question, whether you should use a different data structure is, most probably, "yes" as well, but it's impossible to suggest which one without knowing what it is you are actually trying to do.
Also, don't use `var` - those are evil.

Comment: multiset is a class that contains queues so I think lists where my second choice. why is a queue a wrong thing to use?

Comment: Because a queue is something, that you are supposed to extract elements from the tip, one-by-one, not at arbitrary indexes at the middle. You probably don't need ones at arbitrary indexes either, but, again, no idea what it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert Option[multiSet] to multiSet call get on that again 
ie. `setQueue.get(i).get`

or just`setQueue(i)`